# Excel VBA Change Connection Path but keep delimiter and column formating

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have an excel file that contains one connection to a text file. I need to update the path to this file everyday (as the filename changes for reasons that I can't control). I use the following code to make the change to the path and it works great. The issue is that I lose all other options, like the delimiter separation and also the column data type.

Is there a way I can just change the path and keep the formatting?

Here's the code:

```
Sub Update_Connection()

        Dim Conn As Variant
        Dim ConString As String
        Dim oldPath As String, NewPath As String

        NewPath = "\\Reports\Data\dailydata" & (Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(Format(Now(), "dd"), Format(Now(), "mm"), Format(Now(), "yy")) * 4) & ".txt"
        Debug.Print NewPath

        Set Conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1)

        'Debug.Print Conn.TextConnection.Connection

        ConString = Conn.TextConnection.Connection

        oldPath = Split(ConString, ";")(1)

        ConString = Replace(ConString, oldPath, NewPath)

       Conn.TextConnection.Connection = ConString

    End Sub
```

Comment: if that is the only text file in the folder you can do this once for all with DIR function, regardless of what the name of the text file is it you code can find the file name and take it from there. Can you create a specific folder for this text file and always keep one file there? You can create another folder inside of it and call it previous files, so you can also keep a record of all text files in the past. Also if the name of your text file starts with some predictable string, you can also automate to capture the latest version.

Comment: also one more suggestion is to think about finding the last created file in the folder which is pretty easy. Just loop through files and get the name of the most recently created file. Here is how to get the created date of the file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264090.aspx

Comment: Thanks but finding the file is not the issue. When I change to the new file I lose all of the delimeter snd column data settings

Comment: Why don't you just run the code that creates the connection and make the text file address an argument to the function? That way you can control everything a lot easier. I think you are using split that removed ; from the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer for your specific question, but I would use a method that I can have always the full control on what happens rather than let Excel take care for you because it may differ from a version to another. There are many attributes that you can control and change. I would insert a shape in the workbook you have, right click on it and assign the RunClick sub. Every time you want to pull data from the text file, you just need to click that and everything should be fine. The only part is that you have to develop it more so capture the full name of the most recent text file so you never do anything manually and your data are imported intact.

```
Sub RunClick()
    Dim str As String
    str = "T:\MyFolder\ABC.txt"
    Call CreateConnectionToTextFile(str)
End Sub

Sub CreateConnectionToTextFile(sTextFileFullName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & sTextFileFullName, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "MAKT"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1) 'we have 3 columns that were imported, and all of them are general 1=general text =2 and so on
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    MsgBox "Now Connected Successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

    Exit Sub
```

ErrorHandler:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Connection could not be established.", vbCritical, "Error"
        End If
    End Sub